# Proving that $h=O(\log_2 n)$ if $h=\log_2 (n+1)$

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose that $h=\log_2 (n+1)$. Why is $h$ also $O(\log_2 n)$?

I know the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) of big $O$ notation, and properties or logarithms, but I can't figure it out - that $+1$ is causing troubles.

Answer (score 3):

$\log_2(n+1) < \log_2(n^2) = 2\log_2(n)$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Sufficiently larger than $2$, even. :) For $n\geq 2$, $$n^2 \geq 2n \geq n+n \geq n+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

That's because $\log_2(n+1)\sim_\infty\log_2n$.

Comment: While it's completely correct, the question has a flavor indicating that equivalents are outside the scope (the statement to prove is strictly weaker than the one above).

Comment: Yes, but one can mimic equivalent, thereby proving the existence of a constant $C$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log (n+1) = \log (n(1+\frac  1 n))= \log n + \log \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)$$

Then $\frac {\log (n+1)}{\log n }=\frac {\log n +\log \left( 1 + \frac 1 n\right)}{\log n}\to1$.